# Dynamically creating RedisTemplate for connecting with different Redis server

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

My application is built on spring boot and is backed by Redis datastore. Currently I have a connection only to a single redis server and the properties of that server ( host / port ) is defined in bootstrap.yml.

I want to support multi-tenancy by using a separate Redis server for each customer. In order to do this I need to dynamically connect with various different redis server at runtime. Is it possible with RedisTemplate and JedisConnecitonFactory ?

Answer (score 0):

## In short

No need for multiple `RedisTemplate` instances; implement a routing `RedisConnectionFactory`.

## Explanation

`RedisTemplate` uses an underlying `RedisConnectionFactory` to obtain connections. To route Redis operations to different connections, just implement a routing variant of `RedisConnectionFactory`. `RedisTemplate` asks the associated `RedisConnectionFactory` for each operation to provide a `RedisConnection`.

You need to pay attention when using transactions. Transactional use binds the Redis connection to the calling Thread and `RedisTemplate` works effectively on the same connection until the transaction is finished.

Take a look at [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.java) to get an idea how data source routing is supported for JDBC connections. A routing `RedisConnectionFactory` could follow the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Let me try your option.